# Detect Route Change with react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-redux, react-router-dom

I have to implement some business logic depending on browsing history.

What I want to do is something like this:

```
reactRouter.onUrlChange(url => {
   this.history.push(url);
});
```

Is there any way to receive a callback from react-router when the URL gets updated?

Comment: What version of react-router are you using? That will determine the best approach. I will provide an answer once you update. That being said, the [withRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter) HoC is probably your best bet for making a component location aware. It will update your component with new ({match, history, and location }) anytime a route changes. This way you don't need to manually subscribe and unsubscribe to events. Meaning it is easy to use with functional stateless components as well as class components.

Answer (score 182, accepted):

You can make use of [`history.listen()`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/blob/master/docs/api-reference.md) function when trying to detect the route change. Considering you are using `react-router v4`, wrap your component with `withRouter` HOC to get access to the `history` prop.

`history.listen()` returns an `unlisten` function. You'd use this to `unregister` from listening.

You can configure your routes like

**index.js**

```
ReactDOM.render(
      <BrowserRouter>
            <AppContainer>
                   <Route exact path="/" Component={...} />
                   <Route exact path="/Home" Component={...} />
           </AppContainer>
        </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

and then in **AppContainer.js**

```
class App extends Component {
  
  componentWillMount() {
    this.unlisten = this.props.history.listen((location, action) => {
      console.log("on route change");
    });
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
      this.unlisten();
  }
  render() {
     return (
         <div>{this.props.children}</div>
      );
  }
}
export default withRouter(App);
```

From the history [docs](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/blob/master/docs/api-reference.md#historylistenlistener-listener):

> You can listen for changes to the current location using
> `history.listen`:
>
> ```
> history.listen((location, action) => {
>       console.log(`The current URL is ${location.pathname}${location.search}${location.hash}`)
>   console.log(`The last navigation action was ${action}`)
> })
> ```
>
> The location object implements a subset of the window.location
> interface, including:
>
> ```
> **location.pathname** - The path of the URL
> **location.search** - The URL query string
> **location.hash** - The URL hash fragment
> ```
>
> Locations may also have the following properties:
>
> **location.state** - Some extra state for this location that does not reside in the URL (supported in `createBrowserHistory` and
> `createMemoryHistory`)
>
> `location.key` - A unique string representing this location (supported
> in `createBrowserHistory` and `createMemoryHistory`)
>
> The action is one of `PUSH, REPLACE, or POP` depending on how the user
> got to the current URL.

When you are using react-router v3 you can make use of `history.listen()` from `history` package as mentioned above or you can also make use `browserHistory.listen()`

You can configure and use your routes like

```
import {browserHistory} from 'react-router';

class App extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount() {
          this.unlisten = browserHistory.listen( location =>  {
                console.log('route changes');
                
           });
      
    }
    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.unlisten();
     
    }
    render() {
        return (
               <Route path="/" onChange={yourHandler} component={AppContainer}>
                   <IndexRoute component={StaticContainer}  />
                   <Route path="/a" component={ContainerA}  />
                   <Route path="/b" component={ContainerB}  />
            </Route>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: he's using v3 and the second sentence of your answer says "_Considering you are using `react-router v4`_"

Comment: @KyleRichardson I think you misunderstood me again, I certainly have to work on my english. I meant that if you are using react-router v4 and you are using history object then you need to wrap your component with `withRouter`

Comment: @KyleRichardson I you see my complete answer, I have added ways to do it in v3 also. One more thing, the OP commented that he is using v3 today and I had answerd on the question yesterday

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Yes but the way your answer reads is wrong. He is not using v4... Also, why would you use `history.listen()` when using `withRouter` already updates your component with new props every time routing occurs? You could do a simple comparison of `nextProps.location.href === this.props.location.href` in `componentWillUpdate` to perform anything you need to do if it has changed.

Comment: @KyleRichardson as I said OP mentioned that he is using v3 today and there are multiple ways to do it, 1. make use of history from withRouter 2. make use of history from history package 3. or do a props comparison. However I think do check is compentWillUpdate is not the best solution as it is fired everytime the component needs to update

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri ok :) Sorry if I find your answer hard to follow. It looks like you're suggesting to use `withRouter` AND `history.listen()`.

Comment: @KyleRichardson, I would say, if you are using react-router v4 , follow the first example using history object which is available as prop after you wrap your component with withRouter or use history.listen() or browserHistory.listen() in case of react-router v3

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I would use `withRouter` and do props comparison instead of `history.listen()`.

Comment: @KyleRichardson as I said there are multiple ways to do it, I prefer history.listen and it is also suggessted on the github issue https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/3554

Comment: I used react router v4 with React Router Config. I'm not able to use withRouter to wrap my App component. 
It raise this error:Uncaught Error: You should not use <Route> or withRouter() outside a <Router>.

My app component render logic :
    return <BrowserRouter>{renderRoutes(routes)}</BrowserRouter>;

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri When I change the route using `history.push`, the `listen` doesn't fire, any idea? btw when route changes via `Link`, everything works fine.

Comment: @MehdiDehghani If could be possible that you are using custom history in Router and using push method custom history object whereas you listen to history from props. If thats not the case, could you please provide more details, possibly in a new post

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri What you mean by "you are using custom history in Router"? I passed the props to the child component, then in `componentDidMount` add the listener, and `unlisten` it in the `componentWillUnmount`, and after some ajax req, `this.props.params.history.push('/url');`, the listen doesn't fire in this case

Comment: @MehdiDehghani Why do you read history from params, shouldn't it be `this.props.history.push('/url')`

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri good question, because of redux and its `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` I only have mapped items in the props object. the whole part in my prev comment happens in child component btw. I passed `params` via its parent (_which is stateless component_), e.g `<MyChildCom params={props} />`

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I just tried to use `withRouter` and `this.props.history.push('/url')`, still listen doesn't fire.

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Will it work if I change the url manually in the browser and press enter?

Comment: When I change URL by hand history.listen does not fire also. And I need this.

Comment: Not working for me, I don't know why. The debugger never hit the event line.

Answer (score 183):

### Update for React Router 5.1+.

```js
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

function SomeComponent() {
  const location = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Location changed');
  }, [location]);

  ...
}
```

Comment: when you try to detect change on not changing route this solution works perfect!

Comment: As the user asks, If you try to do `history.push()` in the `useEffect` you will get an infinite loop, so i don't see how this is a solution.

Comment: @Cristian Muscalu, try to replace `location` with `location.pathname` in dependency array.

Comment: This doesn't work for me - it only works when I change url search parameter inside a specific oute, but doesn't work when user click on <Link> to be redirected to different page.

Answer (score 133):

### `react-router v6`

In react-router v6, this can be done by combining the `useLocation` and `useEffect` hooks

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

const MyComponent = () => {
  const location = useLocation()

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // runs on location, i.e. route, change
    console.log('handle route change here', location)
  }, [location])
  ...
}
```

For convenient reuse, you can do this in a custom `useLocationChange` hook

```
// runs action(location) on location, i.e. route, change
const useLocationChange = (action) => {
  const location = useLocation()
  React.useEffect(() => { action(location) }, [location])
}

const MyComponent1 = () => {
  useLocationChange((location) => { 
    console.log('handle route change here', location) 
  })
  ...
}

const MyComponent2 = () => {
  useLocationChange((location) => { 
    console.log('and also here', location) 
  })
  ...
}
```

If you also need to see the previous route on change, you can combine with a `usePrevious` hook

```
const usePrevious = (value) => {
  const ref = React.useRef()
  React.useEffect(() => { ref.current = value })

  return ref.current
}

const useLocationChange = (action) => {
  const location = useLocation()
  const prevLocation = usePrevious(location)
  React.useEffect(() => { 
    action(location, prevLocation) 
  }, [location])
}

const MyComponent1 = () => {
  useLocationChange((location, prevLocation) => { 
    console.log('changed from', prevLocation, 'to', location) 
  })
  ...
}
```

It's important to note that all the above fire on the *first* client route being mounted, as well as subsequent changes. If that's a problem, use the latter example and check that a `prevLocation` exists before doing anything.

Comment: I have a question. If several components have been rendered and they are all watching useLocation then all their useEffects will be triggered. How do I verify that this location is correct for the specific component that will be displayed?

Comment: Hey @Kex - just to clarify `location` here is the browser location, so it's the same in every component and always correct in that sense. If you use the hook in different components they'll all receive the same values when location changes. I guess what they do with that info will be different, but it's always consistent.

Comment: That makes sense. Just wondering how a component will know if the location change is relevant to itself performing an action. Eg a component receives dashboard/list but how does it know if it’s tied to that location or not?

Comment: Unless I do something like if (location.pathName === “dashboard/list”) { ..... actions }. It doesn’t seem very elegant hardcoding path to a component though.

Comment: Using the `useLocation`/`useEffect` method helped get past the "no change after first load" issue on single-page Ionic 5 React projects (using useParams). None of the Ionic Lifecycle methods were triggered after first load.

Comment: How to do this same useLocationChange but with TS? and also react is complaining 

React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'action'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. If 'action' changes too often, find the parent component that defines it and wrap that definition in useCallback  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

Comment: I love this answer, last snippet is very useful. However, as @RubenMarcus said there is a warning. How to make it work without the warning?

Answer (score 19):

If you want to listen to the `history` object globally, you'll have to create it yourself and pass it to the `Router`. Then you can listen to it with its `listen()` method:

```js
// Use Router from react-router, not BrowserRouter.
import { Router } from 'react-router';

// Create history object.
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
const history = createHistory();

// Listen to history changes.
// You can unlisten by calling the constant (`unlisten()`).
const unlisten = history.listen((location, action) => {
  console.log(action, location.pathname, location.state);
});

// Pass history to Router.
<Router history={history}>
   ...
</Router>
```

Even better if you create the history object as a module, so you can easily import it anywhere you may need it (e.g. `import history from './history';`

Comment: When must one call unlisten()? When the whole app unmounts?

Answer (score 13):

This is an old question and I don't quite understand the business need of listening for route changes to push a route change; seems roundabout.

BUT if you ended up here because all you wanted was to update the `'page_path'` on a react-router route change for google analytics / global site tag / something similar, here's a **hook** you can now use. I wrote it based on the accepted answer:

## `useTracking.js`

```
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'

export const useTracking = (trackingId) => {
  const { listen } = useHistory()

  useEffect(() => {
    const unlisten = listen((location) => {
      // if you pasted the google snippet on your index.html
      // you've declared this function in the global
      if (!window.gtag) return

      window.gtag('config', trackingId, { page_path: location.pathname })
    })

    // remember, hooks that add listeners
    // should have cleanup to remove them
    return unlisten
  }, [trackingId, listen])
}
```

You should use this hook *once* in your app, somewhere near the top but still inside a router. I have it on an `App.js` that looks like this:

## `App.js`

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'

import Home from './Home/Home'
import About from './About/About'
// this is the file above
import { useTracking } from './useTracking'

export const App = () => {
  useTracking('UA-USE-YOURS-HERE')

  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/about">
        <About />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/">
        <Home />
      </Route>
    </Switch>
  )
}

// I find it handy to have a named export of the App
// and then the default export which wraps it with
// all the providers I need.
// Mostly for testing purposes, but in this case,
// it allows us to use the hook above,
// since you may only use it when inside a Router
export default () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>
)
```

Comment: i have tried your code but it can not detect when i change a route. it works when i refresh the page. but when is change route the useTracking() is not called again in app.js, is there a way i can make useTracking() get called again when a route changes ?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `useLocation()` Hook to detect the URL change and put it in dependency array in `useEffect()` this trick worked for me

```
const App = () => {

  const location = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    window.scroll(0,0);
  }, [location]);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Routes>
        <Route path={"/"} element={<Template/>} >
          <Route index={true} element={<Home/>} />
          <Route path={"cart"} element={<Cart/>} />
          <Route path={"signin"} element={<Signin/>} />
          <Route path={"signup"} element={<Signup/>} />
          <Route path={"product/:slug"} element={<Product/>} />
          <Route path={"category/:category"} element={<ProductList/>} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

I came across this question as I was attempting to focus the ChromeVox screen reader to the top of the "screen" after navigating to a new screen in a React single page app. Basically trying to emulate what would happen if this page was loaded by following a link to a new server-rendered web page.

This solution doesn't require any listeners, it uses `withRouter()` and the `componentDidUpdate()` lifecycle method to trigger a click to focus ChromeVox on the desired element when navigating to a new url path.

---

### Implementation

I created a "Screen" component which is wrapped around the react-router switch tag which contains all the apps screens.

```js
<Screen>
  <Switch>
    ... add <Route> for each screen here...
  </Switch>
</Screen>
```

---

### `Screen.tsx` Component

**Note:** This component uses React + TypeScript

```js
import React from 'react'
import { RouteComponentProps, withRouter } from 'react-router'

class Screen extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps> {
  public screen = React.createRef<HTMLDivElement>()
  public componentDidUpdate = (prevProps: RouteComponentProps) => {
    if (this.props.location.pathname !== prevProps.location.pathname) {
      // Hack: setTimeout delays click until end of current
      // event loop to ensure new screen has mounted.
      window.setTimeout(() => {
        this.screen.current!.click()
      }, 0)
    }
  }
  public render() {
    return <div ref={this.screen}>{this.props.children}</div>
  }
}

export default withRouter(Screen)
```

I had tried using `focus()` instead of `click()`, but click causes ChromeVox to stop reading whatever it is currently reading and start again where I tell it to start.

**Advanced note:** In this solution, the navigation `<nav>` which inside the Screen component and rendered after the `<main>` content is visually positioned above the `main` using css `order: -1;`. So in pseudo code:

```
<Screen style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
  <main>
  <nav style={{ order: -1 }}>
<Screen>
```

If you have any thoughts, comments, or tips about this solution, please add a comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Sidebar from './Sidebar';
import Chat from './Chat';

<Router>
    <Sidebar />
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/rooms/:roomId" component={Chat}>
            </Route>
        </Switch>
</Router>
```

---

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
function SidebarChat(props) {
    **const history = useHistory();**
    var openChat = function (id) {
        **//To navigate**
        history.push("/rooms/" + id);
    }
}
```

---

```
**//To Detect the navigation change or param change**
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
function Chat(props) {
    var { roomId } = useParams();
    var roomId = props.match.params.roomId;

    useEffect(() => {
       //Detect the paramter change
    }, [roomId])

    useEffect(() => {
       //Detect the location/url change
    }, [location])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the useLocation with `componentDidUpdate` for getting the route change for class component and `useEffect` for functional component

**In Class component**

```
import { useLocation } from "react-router";

class MainApp extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
       super(props);
    }
    async componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
       if(this.props.location.pathname !== prevProps.location.pathname)
       {
         //route has been changed. do something here
       } 
    }
}


function App() {
 const location = useLocation()
 return <MainApp location={location} />
}
```

**In functional component**

```
function App() {
     const location = useLocation()
     useEffect(() => {
        //route change detected. do something here
     }, [location]) //add location in dependency. It detects the location change
     return <Routes> 
              <Route path={"/"} element={<Home/>} >
              <Route path={"login"} element={<Login/>} />
            </Routes>
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**React Router V5**

If you want the pathName as a string ('/' or 'users'), you can use the following:

```
  // React Hooks: React Router DOM
  let history = useHistory();
  const location = useLocation();
  const pathName = location.pathname;
```

Comment: How does this apply to detecting route changes?

Comment: pathname =  window.location.pathname