# Detecting that the back button was pressed in react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have this component that retrieves posts from an api but everytime the user presses the back button, the componentDidMount event is triggered and the api call is repeated.

Does react or react-router provide a way to detect that the back-button was pressed so i can prevent the api call?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { fetchData } from '../actions/actions'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { receivePosts } from '../actions/actions'
import { PostList } from '../components/PostList'
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

class PostListContainer extends Component {


componentDidMount() {            
        this.props.fetchData("posts", receivePosts)
}


render() {
    const { posts, active} = this.props
    return (
        <PostList
            posts={active === '' ? posts : posts.filter( p => p.category === active)}
        />
    )}
}


function mapStateToProps (state) {
    return {
        posts:state.posts,
        active:state.categories.activeFilter
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch)  {
    return {
        receivePosts: () => dispatch(receivePosts()),
        fetchData: (e, h) => dispatch(fetchData(e, h))
    }
}


export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(PostListContainer))
```

Comment: These two question might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45373742/detect-route-change-with-react-router/45373907#45373907 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32841757/detecting-user-leaving-page/45869459#45869459

Comment: Thank you @Shubham Kathri but the following link was a bit more helpful: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39342195/intercept-handle-browsers-back-button-in-react-router)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

to detect the back button in the browser you can use window.onpopstate event, use that in componentDidUpdate like this, this worked for me.

```
componentDidUpdate(){    
  window.onpopstate = e => {
     //your code...
  }
}
```

Comment: how can you then prevent the default back button behaviour and use your own?

Comment: @dan674 it has been a little while but i do not think that there is a default behavior. What was happening in may case was that the api call was getting triggered in componentDidMount lifecycle hook. By detecting that the back button had been pressed, i was able to make the api call conditional. Hope this helps. You can see the code here [link](https://github.com/thierryMic/redeable/blob/master/frontend/src/containers/CategoryContainer.js)

Comment: how to differentiate between forward and back button? Your above code triggers both forward and back.

Answer (score 0):

use `this.props.history.action` in `componentDidMount`
like this :

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

componentDidMount(){
   switch(this.props.history.action){
     case 'PUSH' : // if you go to the page by normal e.g. click link; 
                   break;
     case 'POP' : //  if you go to the page by press back button;  
                   break;
     default :
   }
```

}

Comment: `POP` is also triggered when refreshing page.