# Detect if route is initial page load with Reach Router?

Tags: reactjs, reach-router

I have 2 routes in my app: `/` and `/about`. If a user first visits `/` and then navigates to `/about` then no special behaviour is required. However they refresh the page when on `/about`, or if the initial visit is to `/about` then I need to detect this and do something.

How can I do this? Do I need to `createHistory` first?

https://reach.tech/router/api/createHistory

Comment: Depends. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Im still working out the UX, but probably redirect the user back to the homepage and also dispatch a Redux action.

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45373742/detect-route-change-with-react-router

Comment: I forgot to mention, ill probably also need to get any URL params and pass them to Redux

Comment: @SathishkumarRakkiasamy FYI I'm using Reach Router not React Router.