# React useEffect is not triggering on route change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I expect that `console.log('Refresh')` runs every time the route changes (switching from Component1 to Component2). But it's only triggering on first render. Why?

**`index.js`**:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

ReactDOM.render(<BrowserRouter><App /></BrowserRouter>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**`App.js`**:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Nav from './Nav';
import Component1 from './Component1';
import Component2 from './Component2';

const App = () => {

  useEffect( () => console.log('Refresh'));

  return (
        [<Switch>
            <Route                            component = {Nav}/>
        </Switch>,
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path = '/component1' component = {Component1}/>
            <Route exact path = '/component2' component = {Component2}/>
        </Switch>]
  );
}

export default App;
```

**`Nav.js`**:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const  Nav = () => {
  return (
    <div>
        <Link to = '/component1'>Component 1</Link>
        <Link to = '/component2'>Component 2</Link>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Nav;
```

**`Component1.js`**:

```
import React from 'react';

const  Component1 = () => {

  return (
    <div>
        <p>Hi</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Component1;
```

**`Component2.js`**:

```
import React from 'react';

const  Component2 = () => {
  return (
    <div>
        <p>Bye</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Component2;
```

Comment: Where is your  ```<Router>``` component?

Comment: On **`index.js`** (question updated).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `useEffect` is not triggered because the `App` component is not re-rendered, nothing changed in that component (no state or props update).

If you want the `App` component to re-render when the route change, you can use the `withRouter` HOC to inject route props, like this :

```
import { Switch, Route, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

const App = () => {

  useEffect( () => console.log('Refresh'));

  return (...);
}

export default withRouter(App);
```

Example : https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-pare-n8p1y

Comment: Understood. Good answer.

Comment: this did not resolve my issue. in my case useEffect works as expected UNTIL i navigate to a different route, and come back to current route, and then useEffect doesn't fire, seems to happen regardless of listening to specific state var or not.

Comment: @SonicSoul Could you open a new question with your code ? Seems like a different issue.

Comment: Use this as of 2021 Router V6 https://stackoverflow.com/a/62389224/2394052

Answer (score 19):

use the key attribute so everytime we render new component (different key)

```
<Route path='/mypath/:username' exact render= {routeProps =><MyCompo {...routeProps} key={document.location.href} />} />
```

Comment: You made my day.Thanks you so much

Comment: Cleanest solution to be honest, however my key was a prop to be SSR safe, thanks Aliens

Comment: This should be the top solution. Awesome.

Answer (score 7):

Use the 2nd argument to useEffect to conditionally apply effect. For example via react-router-dom, you get some properties

```js
const { schoolId, classId } = props

useEffect(() => {
   // fetch something here
}, [schoolId, classId)
```

Here `[schoolId, classId` acts as the unique identifier for useEffect to trigger.

Answer (score 7):

**Using Hooks:**

use `useLocation`  and `useLayoutEffect` get **more efficiency**:

```
   import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
//...
   const location = useLocation();
//...
   useLayoutEffect(() => {
    console.log("location",location) 
    
   }, [location])
```

Answer (score 0):

if your are working with an identify `:id` in your route like in

```
 import react from 'react';
 import { Route,Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
 import Properties from './pages/properties';


 function App() {
   return (
           <div>
     <Routes>
         <Route path="/" element={<Home/>} >
            <Route path="properties/:id" element={<Properties/>}/> 
         </Route> 
    </Routes>
 </div>
 );
 }
```

and you want the properties component to `re-render` based on the identify `:id`

you can simply write this way in the properties component

```
 import React,{useEffect} from "react";
 import {  useParams} from "react-router-dom";

 export default Properties(){
   useEffect(()=>{

   return (){...}
  },[useParams.id])


 return <div> .....</div>
 }
```

it will always `re-render` the properties component for every change in the search parameter `:id`