# App useEffect not firing with react router

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, react-router-dom, use-effect

I am trying to add some analytics to my app. At the top level (within App.js) I have a fairly simple layout- a navbar, and outlet (for react router), and a footer. When navigating through the page, the outlet is updated to show my content- shouldn't this call the componentDidUpdate method? I am only seeing my useEffect hook fire after the first render.

If this is operating as expected, is there a better location to place a hook that will be called as a user navigates the page?

(partial) contents of app.js:

```
function App() {

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(window.location.pathname)
  })

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <Navbar />
        <Outlet />
        <Footer />
      </ThemeProvider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

index.js:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <SimpleReactLightbox>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<App />}>
            <Route path="/" element={<Landing />} />
            <Route path="/portfolio" element={<PortfolioGrid />} />
            <Route path="/portfolio" element={<Portfolio />}>
              <Route path=":portfolioId" element={<Portfolio />} />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/aboutme" element={<AboutMe />} />
            <Route path="/downloads" element={<Downloads />}>
              <Route index element={<DefaultDownload />} />  
              <Route path=":downloadId" element={<MyDownloads />} />
            </Route>
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </SimpleReactLightbox>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Can you share a more complete example? I'm guessing there's a router and `Routes` and `Route` components wrapping and rendering `App`? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Updated to include contents of index js - showing the Routes

Comment: Have you considered firing useEffect conditionally ? Check this answer out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62422674/2068732

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't immediately know why using no dependency and logging the `window.location` object doesn't work, but using the currently matched `location` object appears to work. Use the `useLocation` hook and add `location` as the `useEffect` hook's dependency.

Example:

```
import { Outlet, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  const location = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(location.pathname);
  }, [location]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <Navbar />
        <Outlet />
        <Footer />
      </ThemeProvider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit app-useeffect-not-firing-with-react-router]

Comment: Thank you! This works for me. Its still very strange to me that it won't work without the dependency, but I'm still a beginner with react, so I'm sure its something I'm overlooking...

Comment: @witty-user-name It could be that the `window` object isn't aware of anything the routing context from RRD is doing (*all it's doing is manipulating the address bar*), while using the `useLocation` hook to access the routing context *actually* triggers a rerender with the new context value being accessible. This is what I suspect at least.