# create Event on page url changed

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-context

I'm trying to change the page in react-router by calling `history.push` method. but I need an event to listen to page url changes and update context by getting query parameters. how can I declare that event?

Comment: Try `componentDidMount`.

Comment: how? would u clearify? I want to use those params in several components and it's changing from one component.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [Detect Route Change with react-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45373742/detect-route-change-with-react-router/45373907#45373907)

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri i want that listen method outside of <Router> component. but it's not possible.

Comment: You could have  wrap your Top level component with Router

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to change the state with the url parameters right after `history.push` (which is synchronous) which will update your UI.

Reading url parameters from url should be done only on initial mount.

Comment: but I'm using parameters in another component and the only way to share those variables is using context

Comment: ok, one other way is to lift up the props to the closest common ancestor, or to use Redux.

Answer (score 0):

You can send the data required on the next page in `history.push`.

```
 this.props.history.push("/url", { id: 123 })
```

then you can access the parsed data in the next component by following code,

```
const state = this.props.location.state
```

Comment: I don't want using props to pass data through components. because this data is used in several component and 'll mess in code