# React useEffect definition in class

Tags: reactjs, arrow-functions, use-effect

I am trying to set useEffect hook (for listening to route changes) in my class that is defined like -

```
export default class AppManger extends Component{
    //constructor
    //componentWillMount
    //reneder
    //...
}
```

The rest of my hooks are defined and working as expected but when I try to define `useEffect`-

```
useEffect(() => {
        const { pathname } = location;
        console.log('New path:', pathname);
    }, [location.pathname]);
```

I get -
./src/components/AppManger.js

```
  Line 30:  Parsing error: Unexpected token

  28 |         }
  29 |     }
> 30 |     useEffect(() => {
     |               ^
  31 |         const { pathname } = location;
  32 |         console.log('New path:', pathname);
  33 |     }, [location.pathname]);
```

Is it the right way to define arrow function in React component?

Thank you.

Comment: you can't use useEffect (or any hooks) in class components

Comment: butt I use componentWillMount in my class component. I need to listen to route changes.

Comment: that isn't a hook, it's a class component lifecycle function

Comment: put inside the class and check if you import react

Answer (score 0):

No, my friend, you can not use hooks inside class components,
To use you have to convert class component to functional component.
Like this :

```
import React from "react";

export default AppManger = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
        const { pathname } = location;
        console.log('New path:', pathname);
    }, [location.pathname]);
}
```

Comment: I am looking for a way to listen to route change without changing my component.

Comment: Okay, Would you please check this solution : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45373742/detect-route-change-with-react-router

Answer (score 0):

useEffect and all other hooks can be used only in functional components.
In your class component you should use lifecycle methods.
Here is more info: 
1) https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html - lifecycle methods
2) https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html - hooks

Comment: And which lifecycle method will notify when route changes?

Comment: sounds like you might need to ask a new question