# Tracking URL changes with React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

I thought this would be a great question to ask for others to reference later. In my previous revisions I would 'hardcode' five to six sidebars and three to four different top navigation components for each page or section of my app because I couldn't come up with a better solution to determine what page I'm currently on.

[Here's the only resource or example I've found regarding hooks!](https://support.mouseflow.com/support/solutions/articles/44001535025-tracking-url-changes-with-react)

but with the structure of my app, I'm not sure how to approach this.

**index.tsx**:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { ApolloProvider } from '@apollo/react-hooks';
import { apolloClient } from './utils/x';

import Router from './routes/Router';

ReactDOM.render(
  <ApolloProvider client={apolloClient}>
    <Router />
  </ApolloProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);
```

**Router.tsx**:

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

import {
  useHistory,
  BrowserRouter,
  Route,
} from "react-router-dom";

import Landing from './landing/Landing';

import Zero from './dashboard/0';
import One from './dashboard/1';
import Two from './dashboard/2';
import Three from './dashboard/3';

const Router = () => {
    const history = useHistory()

    useEffect(() => {
        return history.listen((location) => {
            console.log(`You changed the page to: ${location.pathname}`)
        })
    },[history])

    return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />

      <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={Zero} />
      <Route exact path="/dashboard/1" component={One} />
      <Route exact path="/dashboard/2" component={Two} />
      <Route exact path="/dashboard/3" component={Three} />
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

export default Router;
```

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'history' of undefined`

I'm probably so far fetched and out of scope, but I would love to figure this out...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect Route Change with react-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45373742/detect-route-change-with-react-router)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got to thinking as soon as I wrote the last sentence, I was indeed out of scope

```js
    const history = useHistory()

    useEffect(() => {
        return history.listen((location) => {
            console.log(`You changed the page to: ${location.pathname}`)
        })
    },[history])
```

The following code works well and would go in the components listed in the router

Comment: Putting that code into each component will create lots of duplicate code; here's how to insert a listener so you can track changes in a single spot: https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-nobel-foo6v?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @ChrisG That also works! Thanks for the live demo :)

Comment: Feel free to edit your answer accordingly, because duplicate code is bad practice; there's also this existing question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45373742/detect-route-change-with-react-router

Comment: This will not work in react 17+, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68613526/react-router-dom-usehistory-not-working