# react-router-dom useHistory() not working

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, redux-thunk

The **useHistory()** hook is not working in my project. I have it in different components but none of them work.
I am using "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",

```
import {useHistory} from 'react-router-dom'

const history = useHistory()

const logout = () => {    
   toggleMenu()
   setUser(null)
   dispatch({type: 'LOGOUT'})
   history.push('/')
}
```

And also in action its not working

```
export const signin = (formdata, history, setError) => async (dispatch) => {
try {
    const {data} = await API.signIn(formdata)
    if(data.error){
        setError(data.message)
    }else{
        dispatch({type: SIGNIN, data})
        history.push('/dashboard')
    }

   } catch (error) {
    setError(error)
    console.log(error)
  }
}
```

Here is my router.js file

```
const Router = () => {
    const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('profile'))
    return (
       <BrowserRouter>
                <>
                    {user && <Navigation/>}
                    <Switch>
                        <Route path='/page-not-found' component={Auth}/>
                        <Route path='/' exact component={()=>((user && user.result) ? <Redirect to="/dasboard"/> : <Auth/>)} />
                        
                        <Route path='/dashboard' component={() => (user ? <Dashboard/> : <Redirect to='/'/>)} />
                        <Route path='/books-purchase' component={() => (user ? <BooksPage/> : <Redirect to='/' />)} />
                    
                    </Switch>
                </>
            
        </BrowserRouter>
      )
  }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Is it erroring out? Nothing happening at all?

Comment: Nothing is happening

Comment: What about the dispatch and the state set, are they working?

Comment: Yes everything is working fine except history.push()

Comment: We need to see more code then. Can you share where you initialize your routes and the rest of the component calling history.push?

Comment: Is the URL in browser changed when history.push("/") is executed?

Comment: It just blinked

Comment: Console log history object u are getting using hook let history = useHistory (); If that object is not undefined, then there is something wrong with your code

Comment: yes it returned undefined

Comment: it returned undefined and no error occured

Comment: This error can be thrown when one of Router and the useHistory hook are imported from react-router and the other one from react-router-dom and the package versions of those packages don't match. If that's the case. don't use both of them

Comment: Both are imported form react-router-dom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some investigation, I found that there is a bug in `react-router-dom` version `^5.2.0`. See [this](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/issues/804) and [this](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2020/10/22/react-router-v5-fix-for-redirects-not-rendering-when-using-custom-history) .  I would suggest you to downgrade `react-router-dom` version to `4.10.1`

Comment: You are welcome :) I'm glad that everything is working now! Cheers!

Answer (score 12):

- For the version of `react router dom` less than `6.^`

You can use `useHistory()` hook like your code is showing

- For the latest version of `react router dom` greater than `6.^`

You can use `useNavigate()` hook like this. You can also use without props

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

class Login extends Component {
  ....

  let navigate = useNavigate();

      navigate('/');
    
    .....
```

Answer (score 6):

In my point of view, It doesn't need to downgrade `react-router-dom`, just use "useNavigate" hook instead of "useHistory" hook. For example if you also want to send some data to your dashboard page, you can use it like so:

```js
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'

const FunctionalComponent = () => {
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const TestHandler = (someData) => {
        navigate("/dashboard", {state: {someData: someData}});
        //and if you don't want to send any data use like so:
        //navigate("/dashboard");
    }
}
```

Finally, if you want to use that sent data for example in your dashboard page, you can do it like so:

```html
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'

export const Dashboard = () => {
    const location = useLocation();


    useEffect(() => {
        if (location.state.someData) {
            // "someData" is available here.
        }
    });
```

You can refer to this migration guide: https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5

Comment: How can I read the state: {someData: someData} in the landed page? I tried props.state.someData but returns undefined

Comment: Hi @Butri, sorry for delaying, I edited my answer.

Comment: Great answer, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Instead of `useHistory`, try `useNavigate`:

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
```

Comment: What about legacy code?

Answer (score 0):

i have same error, I forgot add type to button that working function. when i give type,problem was solved

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes, if we call history in dialog or modal it shows error, pass the method to components

```
const methodTopass= () => {
    history.push("/route");
};

<componet methodTopass/>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

left `"react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",`
 add  `"history": "4.10.1",` in to package.json 
then use `import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";`
and 
`let hist = createBrowserHistory();`
`hist.push("/domoy");`