# How to trigger a function on route change?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

My routes:

```
<Provider store={store}>
  <Router>
    <Fragment>
      <Navbar />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact={true} path="/" component={Landing} />
        <Route exact={true} path="/register" component={Register} />
        <Route exact={true} path="/login" component={Login} />
        <Route path="*" exact={true} component={PageNotFound} />
      </Switch>
    </Fragment>
  </Router>
</Provider>
```

I just want to trigger some functions like dispatch etc. whenever I move from a route to a different route. for e.g when I move from "/register'" to "/login", I want to use dispatch to modify my store's state.
What is a good way to go about it?

Comment: use can use `history.listen()`

Comment: checkout this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45373742/detect-route-change-with-react-router

Answer (score 0):

Read This Answer:

### [How to listen to route changes in react router v4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41911309/how-to-listen-to-route-changes-in-react-router-v4)

Example :

```
class Router extends React.Component {

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.location !== prevProps.location) {
      this.changedRoute();
    }
  }

  changedRoute() {
    console.log("route Changed, new location : ",this.props.location);
  }

  render(){
    return (
       <BrowserRouter>
          <Switch>
             <Route path="/" exact component={Landing} />
             <Route path="/register" component={Register} />
             <Route path="/login" component={Login} />

             <Route component={NotFound} />
          </Switch>
       </BrowserRouter>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You able to dispatch action from component that you pass to the Route component. If your component is based on class use `componentDidMount`. If your component is FunctionComponent use `useEffect`.

For example for `<Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />` your Login component should be.

```
const Login = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    dispatch({ type: 'login' });
  }, [dispatch]);
};
```