# Listen to Route Change in reach-router

Tags: reactjs, reach-router

When the route change from a component I want to change the redux store value. I am using the reach router. I want to perform something like this:

```
   React.useEffect(() => {
    // want to change redux store value here
  }, [if route changes then the use-effect will trigger]);
```

Comment: what is version of react-router?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect Route Change with react-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45373742/detect-route-change-with-react-router)

Comment: I am using react/reach. not using react router

Comment: Look at https://reach.tech/router/api/LocationProvider