# check user inactivity throughout the component in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have react app with several routes rendering several components. How do i check user inactivity for all the pages. If user is inactive in any of the page for more than 5 mins, I want a function to be executed which does some operation, if user does some activities like click, enter etc the inactivity time should be reset back to 5 mins.

Looked into these answers but wasn't able to do it.

[How to detect idle time in JavaScript elegantly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667555/how-to-detect-idle-time-in-javascript-elegantly)

[How to auto log off when a user is inactive in ReactJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40888776/how-to-auto-log-off-when-a-user-is-inactive-in-reactjs)

Can it be done using only vanilla Javascript without any packages?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Did you try https://stackoverflow.com/a/10126042/5773530? What doesn't work?

Answer (score 13):

Package [react-idle-timer](https://github.com/supremetechnopriest/react-idle-timer) will do the work for you.

You can install it like this,

```sh
sudo npm install react-idle-timer
```

or

```sh
npm install react-idle-timer --save
```

## Component Usage

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import IdleTimer from 'react-idle-timer'

export default class YourApp extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.idleTimer = null
    this.handleOnAction = this.handleOnAction.bind(this)
    this.handleOnActive = this.handleOnActive.bind(this)
    this.handleOnIdle = this.handleOnIdle.bind(this)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <IdleTimer
          ref={ref => { this.idleTimer = ref }}
          timeout={1000 * 60 * 15}
          onActive={this.handleOnActive}
          onIdle={this.handleOnIdle}
          onAction={this.handleOnAction}
          debounce={250}
        />
        {/** Your app/component here. */}
      </div>
    )
  }

  handleOnAction (event) {
    console.log('user did something', event)
  }

  handleOnActive (event) {
    console.log('user is active', event)
    console.log('time remaining', this.idleTimer.getRemainingTime())
  }

  handleOnIdle (event) {
    console.log('user is idle', event)
    console.log('last active', this.idleTimer.getLastActiveTime())
  }
}
```

## Hook Usage

```js
import React from 'react'
import { useIdleTimer } from 'react-idle-timer'
import App from './App'

export default function (props) {
  const handleOnIdle = event => {
    console.log('user is idle', event)
    console.log('last active', getLastActiveTime())
  }

  const handleOnActive = event => {
    console.log('user is active', event)
    console.log('time remaining', getRemainingTime())
  }

  const handleOnAction = event => {
    console.log('user did something', event)
  }

  const { getRemainingTime, getLastActiveTime } = useIdleTimer({
    timeout: 1000 * 60 * 15,
    onIdle: handleOnIdle,
    onActive: handleOnActive,
    onAction: handleOnAction,
    debounce: 500
  })

  return (
    <div>
      {/** Your app/component here. */}
    </div>
  )
}
```

They offer a lot of feature which you can read here on GitHub at [react-idle-timer](https://github.com/supremetechnopriest/react-idle-timer)